# Understanding visually a change of variables (coordinate systems) in two dimensions.

Tags: coordinate-systems, change-of-variable

I understand visually what happens when we move from $(x,y)$ space to $(r,\theta)$ space, or vice versa.

But can someone explain to me this change of variables, $(\xi,\eta), \xi=x+y,\eta=x-y.$ Which points get map to where?

Thanks.

Comment: why not try it yoursel? Draw two copies of the plane and for a start, ask yourself simple questions like where do points such as $(0,0), (1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ in the $x,y$ plane get mapped to?

Comment: I have a guess for some points, e.g. the x axis gets mapped to $\xi=\eta$, the y axis gets mapped to $\xi=-\eta$, so I thought it could be a 45 degree rotation, but this is not true when I just plug in a random point, so I'm not too sure how to visualise the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's a good start. You're right about where the lines are getting mapped. Note that the $x$-axis being mapped to $\{\xi=\eta\}$ and $y$-axis being mapped to $\{\xi=-\eta\}$ already should suggest to you something fishy is going on, because the orientation seems to have been reversed, so some type of reflection must be taking place. Next, if $(x,y)=(1,0)$ then $(\xi,\eta)=(1,1)$, so something of length $1$ gets distorted to something of length $\sqrt{2}$; this suggests to us that pure rotation/reflection is out of the question. Consider the following three functions:

- $f_1:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, $f_1(x,y)=(y,x)$ ,
- $f_2:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, $f_2(a,b)=(\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}})$,
- $f_3:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, $f_3(\alpha,\beta):=(\sqrt{2}\alpha,\sqrt{2}\beta)$.

Now, $f_1$ simply reflects across the line $\{x=y\}$, since we're just swapping the roles of $x$ and $y$. Next, $f_2$ takes a point $(a,b)$ and rotates it counter clockwise by $45^{\circ}$, or $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians (the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is precisely the cosine and sine of $\frac{\pi}{4}$). Lastly, $f_3$ takes a point $(\alpha,\beta)$ and rescales by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$. Now consider the triple composition $f=f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$. If you carry out the computation, you'll see that
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\cdots =(x+y,x-y)
\end{align}
Thus, the change of variables $\xi=x+y,\eta=x-y$ is simply the mapping $f$ I have just written down for you. So, it does three things: first reflects across the diagonal, then rotates counter clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and finally rescales by $\sqrt{2}$.

---

Since these are all linear transformations, we can also reword the argument above in terms of matrices (of the $f$'s with respect to the standard ordered basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$):
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
1&-1
\end{pmatrix}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2}&0\\
0&\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
The matrices, going right to left are the reflection across the diagonal, rotation counter clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and scaling by $\sqrt{2}$. So, this is just another way of confirming what I already said above.

Answer (score 0):

yes you just charge the coordinate system to the new axes $x=y ,;and x=-y$
example: $(t^2,t)$ black to,  $(t^2+t,t^2-t)$green [image: see picture]